# Is there a way for a Child component to be able to call a siblings function.

Tags: angular

I have two components that have the same parent. There is a search button in component 1 and a refresh button in component 2. I want both of this buttons to do the same thing and call a function in component 1. Is there a way for component 2 to call the function in component 1 or be able to click on the search button.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating an EventEmitter refresh in Child2 component. When refresh button is click it would Emit the Event to the Parent component.  The parent component would then call search on the child component using a template variable.

```
//home component
     //child 1 with variable
    <search #Search><search>
//html code
     ///child 2 calling search on child 1. 
    <results (refreshEvent)="Search.onSearch()"></results>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to leverage the @ViewChild decorator, you have to use parent-child relationship between component1 and component2 in order to call a function from one of them from the other, to reference the child (component1) component from the parent one (component2) by injection:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from 'angular2/core';  

(...)

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
    <child></child>
    <button (click)="someOtherMethod()">Call Function from Comp1</button>
  `,
  directives:[Component1]
})
export class AppComponent { 
  @ViewChild(Component1) comp1:Component1;

  (...)

  someOtherMethod() {
    this.comp1.functToCallInComp1();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this? is there a workaround?

Comment: What do you want, not nested components? In that case you have to think on create a service with the function that you want to call on both components and inject it on them...

Comment: @DiegoUnanue this is great for hierarchical components but it doesn't solve  for siblings like the OP requested.